# C++ input question

Tags: c++, input, controller

I am attempting to build a small local-purpose 3d engine, which has to be *platform-independent* and right now I'm looking for a way to handle different possible types of user input.

This, obviously, includes mouse / keyboard events and possibly, another analogue controllers (joysticks, for example). *I can think of several ways to implement this and am seeking for an advice - what would be better.*

So far, I can write my own controller event handling and dispatching module, reimplement the whole functionality myself, though I guess I would face some troubles making this work for different platforms and integrating it. ***That's the hardest and the reinventing way.***

Another approach would mean reusing some existing scheme / library for this sort of things, but I can't come with a good choice. `Qt` seems like an overkill for my small library, `allegro` and other `SDL-like` libraries have pretty tight logic coupling and writing a generic wrapper around them could become even harder then rewriting everything from scratch.

**Maybe there is some appropriate library, which could help me in this situation?**

*What would you do?*

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[OIS](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wgois/) is pretty good.  It's the default one that the [OGRE](http://www.ogre3d.org/) tutorials use.